# Syntax In Access 2010 IIF Query

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am a beginning user of Access, and am trying to build a query inside of a form.

I am working on my first IIF query, and am having trouble getting the desired behavior.

I am trying to pull results based on 4 entries, called [band], [band2], [band3] and [band4].

Here is where I'm at:

```
Like IIf(IsNull([forms]![financial_filter]![band]),"*",[forms]![financial_filter]![band]) Or Like [forms]![financial_filter]![band2] Or Like [forms]![financial_filter]![band3] Or Like [forms]![financial_filter]![band4]
```

This means that if the [band] field is empty, it will pull all results for all bands. But if the [band] and/or [band2-4] fields are filled in, it will pull results from only those fields. This is all working.

BUT, if a user leaves the [band] field empty and only enters something in the [band 2-4] fields, all results show up, not just those related to the data in the [band 2-4] fields. Please advise how to modify my query so that if a user chooses one or more bands but does not put anything into the [band] field, only the selected results will populate.

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

IIF has nothing to do with Query.
The IIF statement is a shortcut for a IF .. THEN .. ELSE .. END IF statement.

`MyResult =IIF (Condition, Make1, Make2)` means

```
IF Condition THEN
   MyResult=Make1
ELSE
   MyResult= Make2
END IF
```

You can nest IIF statements, but the result will be difficult to read and also to maintain.

So, in your case I would suggest to write a couple of lines with your business logic (IF THEN ELSE END IF) or (IF THEN ELSEIF ... END IF) in the OnCurrent Event of your form, improving future maintenance and readability of your code.

Comment: Thank you Cisco! That makes sense...I'll isolate all the conditions with several If/Then/Else statements!